# Can I execute a function in "apply" to pandas dataframe asynchronously?

Tags: python, pandas, asynchronous

I have a pandas dataframe and on each row, I would like to execute a function. However, the function includes I/O call to a remote server and thus it is very slow if I call it simply using `.apply()` to the dataframe.

Here is an example:

```
def f(data):
    r = requests.get(data["url"])
    x = process(r.content)
    y = process_2(r.content)
    z = process_3(r.content)
    print("Done")

    return [x, y, z]

df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis=1)
```

In this code, the problem is `requests.get(data["url"])` takes a while and thus the entire `apply()` function is very slow at finishing. The `print()` is printed on the console at a few seconds of interval.

Is it possible to execute the `apply()` function asynchronously and get the result faster? My dataframe has 5,000+ rows and the function call to each raw should take a few seconds.

Comment: Have you tried dask dataframe, it is a tool for distributed dataframes and can be used as a layer on the top of pandas

Comment: Don't bother. Take the URLs out of the DF in a list and pass them to something like requests-futures to make async calls with a callback function to do the rest of the processing. Then put the results back into the DF. Purely my opinion, but pandas just gets in the way for this kinda thing IMO

Comment: Try dask delayed

Comment: @RobinNicole I have never heard of it, will check it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Asynchronous I/O* approach with well-known [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) + [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request) libraries:

Demonstrated on sample Dataframe and simple webpage content processing routines (to show the mechanics of the approach).
Let's say we need to count all *header*, *link*(`<a>`) and *span* tags through all *urls* and store the resulting counters in the source dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def count_headers(html):
    return len(list(html.select('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6')))

def count_links(html):
    return len(list(html.find_all('a')))

def count_spans(html):
    return len(list(html.find_all('spans')))


df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'url': ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions',
                                            'https://facebook.com',
                                            'https://wiki.archlinux.org']})
df['head_c'], df['link_c'], df['span_c'] = [None, None, None]
# print(df)

async def process_url(df, url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        resp = await session.get(url)
        content = await resp.text()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
        headers_count = count_headers(soup)
        links_count = count_links(soup)
        spans_count = count_spans(soup)
        print("Done")

        df.loc[df['url'] == url, ['head_c', 'link_c', 'span_c']] = \
            [[headers_count, links_count, spans_count]]


async def main(df):
    await asyncio.gather(*[process_url(df, url) for url in df['url']])
    print(df)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(df))
loop.close()
```

The output:

```
Done
Done
Done
   id                                  url  head_c  link_c  span_c
0   1  https://stackoverflow.com/questions      25     306       0
1   2                 https://facebook.com       3      55       0
2   3           https://wiki.archlinux.org      15      91       0
```

Enjoy the performance difference.

Comment: I think this is a elegant solution. I like it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still struggling, but does this work only if you directly call the GET request via `aiohttp` method? If the function I use to do the get request is from a third-party library and does not use `asyncio` in it, can I also call it asynchronously?

Comment: Ok, it seems that `asyncio`'s `run_in_executor` is suitable for this purpose.

Comment: @Blaszard, asyncio is a common and builtin stuff and is often a perfect fit for IO-bound and high-level structured network code. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html. You'll gain a lot of good from of dealing with it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: How would you implement a request per minute limit in your solution?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest don't know if still relevant, but you can take a look at this: https://github.com/mjpieters/aiolimiter . It has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea for an optimized apply for Pandas is to use Swifter
https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter

Answer (score 1):

The solution using dask is simple:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

npartitions = 24
dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=npartitions).apply(lambda x: f(x), meta=list, axis=1).compute()
```

A more common use-case might be for the apply function to return a dataframe. For that, you want to `return pd.Series({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})` in your function and then pass e.g. `meta={'x': float, 'y': float, 'z': float}` to `apply`.