# How to iterate over dataframe rows for individual API calls

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, loops

I'm trying to set up a loop to pull in weather data for about 500 weather stations for an entire year which I have in my dataframe. The base URL stays the same, and the only part that changes is the weather station ID.

I'd like to create a dataframe with the results. I believe i'd use requests.get to pull in data for all the weather stations in my list, which the IDs to use in the URL are in a column called "API ID" in my dataframe. I am a python beginner - so any help would be appreciated! My code is below but doesn't work and returns an error:
"InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0 "  [http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/...\nName](http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/...%5CnName): API ID, Length: 497, dtype: object'
.

```
def callAPI(API_id):
    for IDs in range(len(API_id)):

        url = ('http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries&dataTypes=PRCP,SNOW,TMAX,TMIN&stations=' + distances['API ID'] + '&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-12-31&includeAttributes=0&includeStationName=true&units=standard&format=json')
        r = requests.request('GET', url)
            
        d = r.json()

ll = [] 
for index1,rows1 in distances.iterrows():
        station = rows1['Closest Station']
        API_id = rows1['API ID']     
        data = callAPI(API_id)
        ll.append([(data)])
```

Comment: `print(url)` inside your for loop and see what's inside it? also, I am not sure how you are referring `+ distances['API ID'] + ` inside the function

Comment: @AlwaysSunny the print function says url is undefined.. am i referring to the api id wrong? that column is the one that contains the ID for weather stations that changes based on station

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your whole code base, but this is the function that will return the data from the API, **If you have multiple station id on a single df column then you can use a `for` loop otherwise no need to do that.**

Also, you are not returning the result from the function. Check the `return` keyword at the end of the function.

**Working code:**

```
import  requests
def callAPI(API_id):
    url = ('http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries&dataTypes=PRCP,SNOW,TMAX,TMIN&stations=' + API_id + '&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-12-31&includeAttributes=0&includeStationName=true&units=standard&format=json')
    r = requests.request('GET', url)
    d = r.json()
    return d

print(callAPI('USC00457180'))
```

So your full code will be something like this,

```
def callAPI(API_id):
    url = ('http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries&dataTypes=PRCP,SNOW,TMAX,TMIN&stations=' + API_id + '&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-12-31&includeAttributes=0&includeStationName=true&units=standard&format=json')
    r = requests.request('GET', url)
    d = r.json()
    return d

ll = [] 
for index1,rows1 in distances.iterrows():
    station = rows1['Closest Station']
    API_id = rows1['API ID']     
    data = callAPI(API_id)
    ll.append([(data)])
```

**Note:** Even better use asynchronous calls to the API to make the process faster. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926297/1138192

Comment: Thank you! this was helpful. I do have multiple station ids in the df column, there are about 500 rows or so, and each row has a unique ID. However, this code gives me back an error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Post your `distances` value then

Comment: distances is the name of the dataframe, and i can't share that data unfortunately