# Faster approach to collect text data from multiple URL and save it to the dataframe rowwise for each URL

Tags: pandas, multithreading, text, nlp, urllib

I have a `DataFrame` of shape `(700000,5)`. One column of the `DataFrame` has single unique text file URL

Example:
Two columns showing for reference:

| Task identifier | Text url |
| --- | --- |
| ub12345567 | https:/ / someadd. txt |
| ub12345569 | https:/ / someadd.txt |

I want to create third column like this:

| text |
| --- |
| text from url 1 |
| text from url 2 |

collect text from URL of 'text url' column from same row and paste it to 'text' column.

I used following code for this task

```py
def text(txt):
  d=urlopen(txt).read().decode()
  return d
df['txt']=df['Text url'].apply(text)
```

But it's taking so long time, from last night code is running only. Can anyone suggest it to make faster for 700000 rows.
Few text files might have more than 2000 words.
Please suggest a faster solution. I am using a server, which has 64gb ram and an I7 processor.

Comment: you can apply the following approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926297/3185459

Comment: can you help me on suggested solution for my case

Comment: @Remerem study that approach and apply it in similar way excepting of calling `count_` functions

Comment: HI @RomanPerekhrest thx for your answer, i am getting error this event loop is already running. restarted kernel but error is same